# How to create array from number, based on digits number in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I need to translate ASCII code in HEX to characters. I got from server numbers(as string) in ascii, like: 64656661756c74 (which means 'default'). I know about String.fromCharCode(), but first i need to split the raw message to 2-digits pieces(array). How can i split 2-digits-duration based?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that ASCII is correct? I believe it should be `68 69 70 65 85 76 84`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This community is focused on solving specific programming issues, so questions like "How do I ...?" are often too broad. You should try and figure it out your self, and if you run into any specific problems post those here and I'm sure you'll get help.

Comment: What kind of server returns text as hex strings?! Looks broken to me.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question, yes, its ASCII in hex. The server that returns such an answers is 'Grass valley K2 summit'. Its AMP control protocol.

Comment: Yes, since, other than UTF-16, JavaScript doesn't have character encoding libraries intrinsically, you could rely on the ASCII encoding of the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block being the same as the UTF-16 encoding and use `fromCharCode`; Or rely on the ASCII encoding for that block being the same as the ASCII codepoints _and_ the Unicode codespoints and use `fromCodePoint`. IMO, that's worthy of a code comment.

Comment: On the other hand, the [AMP Spec](http://www.gvgdevelopers.com/Protocols/AMP_SDK/Docs/AMP_Spec.pdf) says that only names are in ASCII, general character data is in UTF-8. (In general, ASCII is used so rarely, it's always advisable to refer to a relevant spec when ASCII is mentioned.)

Answer (score 4):

Since the string is hex string representation, you have also to convert in decimal number before you pass to `String.fromCharCode`:

```js
const str = "64656661756c74"
              .match(/.{2}/g)
              .map(ch => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(ch, 16)))
              .join("");
              
console.log(str);
// "default"
```

That basically store in `str` the value "default", as you said.

Comment: Nice solution. .

Answer (score 2):

Using `replace`:

```js
let a = '64656661756c74';

let r = a.replace(/([0-9a-f]{2})/g, (m, a) => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a, 16)))

console.log(r)
```

Oldschool approach:

```js
let a = '64656661756c74', r = '';

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i+=2)
  r += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a.substring(i, i+2), 16))

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

To split that into 2-character chunks, use a regular expression like so:

```js
var str = '64656661756c74';
str = str.match(/.{1,2}/g);
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments above, your ASCII sequence is probably incorrect. Maybe it is a hexadecimal stream.

Assuming the correct ASCII numbers,
you can go as following,

```js
var str = '68697065857684';
str = str.match(/.{1,2}/g);


for (index = str.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
  var temp = str[index];  
  str[index]= String.fromCharCode(temp);
}

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Yes, it's hex (decimal doesn't make sense), and it's lowercase!

Comment: You are right @Bergi

I've seen a text stream in hex for the first time though :)

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question, yes, its ASCII in hex. The server that returns such an answers is 'Grass valley K2 summit'. Its AMP control protocol.